# Accessing dynamically generated dropdownlist in Gridview_RowUpdating event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using Gridview with AutoGenerateColumns="True", so gridview columns are generated dynamically. Now in case of edit, I am adding dropdownlist dynamically for one of the field in the gridview. Please see following code:

```
    protected void grdViewConfig_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        grdViewConfig.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;            
        BindGridView();

        clientBAL = new TMIWsBALClient();
        var lstAppIds = clientBAL.GetDistinctApplicationIds();

        GridViewRow grdRow = grdViewConfig.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

        for (int i = 0; i < grdRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (grdRow.Cells[i].GetType().Equals(typeof(DataControlFieldCell)))
            {
                DataControlFieldCell dcField = (DataControlFieldCell )grdRow.Cells[i];
                if (dcField.ContainingField.HeaderText.ToLower().Equals("applicationid"))
                {                        

                    DropDownList drpDwnAppIds = new DropDownList();
                    drpDwnAppIds.ID = "drpDwnAppIds";
                    drpDwnAppIds.DataSource = lstAppIds;                        
                    drpDwnAppIds.DataBind();

                    var tb = dcField.GetAllControlsOfType<TextBox>(); ;// grdRow.Cells[i].GetAllControlsOfType<TextBox>();
                    TextBox firstTb = (TextBox)tb.First();                        
                    foreach (ListItem lstItem in drpDwnAppIds.Items)
                    {
                        if (firstTb.Text.Equals(lstItem.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            lstItem.Selected = true;
                        }
                    }

                    dcField.Controls.Remove(firstTb);
                    dcField.Controls.Add(drpDwnAppIds);
                }
            }               

        }            

    }
```

Now in Gridview_RowUpdating event, I am trying to fetch the dropdownlist in similar way, but I am unable to get it. GetAllControlsOfType() is an extension method, which will return all the child controls under selected parent. In this case, parent is gridview cell and child control is dropdownlist. But it is returning null.

```
    protected void grdViewConfig_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        strTableName = txtTable.Text.Trim();

        string strAppId;
        GridViewRow grdRow = grdViewConfig.Rows[grdViewConfig.EditIndex];

        for (int i = 0; i < grdRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (grdRow.Cells[i].GetType().Equals(typeof(DataControlFieldCell)))
            {
                DataControlFieldCell dcField = (DataControlFieldCell)grdRow.Cells[i];
                if (dcField.ContainingField.HeaderText.ToLower().Equals("applicationid"))
                {
                    var drpDwn = dcField.GetAllControlsOfType<DropDownList>();
                    DropDownList drpDwnAppIds = (DropDownList)drpDwn.First();
                    strAppId = drpDwnAppIds.SelectedValue;
                }
            }

        }           

    }
```

What am I missing? Please help. Also let me know if more information is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generated controls need to be recreated on every postback. In your case the DropDownList controls you created no longer exist when you hit the grdViewConfig_RowUpdating handler.

Generally in this sort of case you would set AutoGenerateColumns to false and manually define your columns which would allow you to define a TemplateField which contains an ItemTemplate for read only mode and an EditItemTemplate for edit mode which could then contain your DropDownList.